# How to view the namespaces range of a Docker container to choose correct Samba domain member idmap range?

Tags: docker, samba, docker-container

I created Samba domain member file share server in a Docker container, but actually I am not sure if the namespace range which I used for samba was optimal, because at some points I got always some errors about the range, I kept trying till it worked!

I am not sure but I think that the problem was because Samba in runnung inside Docker container, which means that I have just a specific Namespaces range to use.

**Could some one please tell me how can I view the namespaces used for a Docker container?** I tried this but it didn't work as I couldn't find `uid_map` file.

```
cat /proc/$(docker inspect -f '{{ .State.Pid }}' redis-userns)/uid_map
```